# Filter e Join com Django ORM

Tags: python, django, orm

Eu tenho 2 tabelas , uma chamada FormsItems e outra chamada FormsTypes.
FormsItems tem uma FK para FormsTypes onde é indicado o tipo do campo que aquele item é.
Usando SQL eu consegui fazer um join entre essas tabelas assim:

```
SELECT formitems.id,formitems.name, formitems.classification, formitems.onchange, formitems.forms_id,
       formitems.form_types_id, formtypes.name
FROM service_request_formitems formitems
    inner join service_request_formtypes formtypes
    on formitems.forms_id = 42 and formtypes.id = formitems.form_types_id;
```

Eu preciso fazer a mesam coisa, só que usando o ORM do DJango porém nao estou conseguindo, o que eu tenho até agora no django é o seguinte código:

```
def formulario(self, request):
        itemId = 81
        item = Items.objects.get(id=itemId)
        itemForId = item.forms.id
        formsItems = FormItems.objects.filter(forms_id=itemForId).order_by('classification')
```

Porém ele não faz o join e  me retorna o campo nome da tabela FormTypes.

Não tenho experiencia nem com sql nem com o ORM do django, eu sei o basico e to tentando avançar entao qualquer ajuda com isso eu agradeço.

Os meu models são :

```
class FormItems(models.Model):
    form_types = models.ForeignKey(
        'FormTypes', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.TextField(null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    classification = models.IntegerField()
    onchange = models.TextField(null=True)

class FormTypes(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes utilizar as tuas queries diretamente, mas podendo utilizar o ORM, muitas coisa são bem mais fácil.

Precisas de fazer algo assim, utilizar o operador "select_related" do ORM de Django:

```
def formulario(self, request):
    # ...
    FormItems.objects.select_related('form_types').filter(forms_id=itemForId).order_by('classification')
```

Podes efetuar filtro pelo teu form types diretamente, assim:

```
FormItems.objects.select_related('form_types').filter(form_types__id=id).order_by('classification')
```